# Rails: Complex Active Record Query - Order child records based on number of siblings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

http://www.trailerpuppy.com/trailers/popular

A trailer belongs_to a Movie. A Movie has_many trailers and has_many notifications. I want to return the most recent trailer from the movies with the most notifications

trailer.rb

```
 def self.most_reminders_set(from_date, until_date, number_to_return)
    Trailer.joins(:movie => :notifications).
          where("movies.release_date > ?", from_date).
          where("movies.release_date < ?", until_date).
          select('trailers.*, COUNT(notifications.id) AS notifications_count').
          joins(:movie).group('trailers.id').
          order('notifications_count DESC').take(number_to_return).first(number_to_return)
end
```

So basically this method allows me to set a timeframe and then it will return the top X trailers (whos movies have the most notifications).

The issue with this is that I am getting multiple trailers for the same movie. I only want to return one trailer per unique movie_id.

Not sure where to add that in my query.

Comment: You can do `where(movies: { release_date: [from_date..until_date] })` to clean it up slightly. Have you tried grouping on `movies.id` instead?

Answer (score 0):

You need a subquery to get the latest trailer. Also, I noticed you are using `joins` twice for `movies` which you don't need to. Here is the link to a good article related to your problem:

http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/